# VB.NET & SOAP - More than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am trying to call the webservice that can be seen at:
http://www.flexiblecarhire.com/flexibleservice/fchxmlinterface.asmx?op=GetAirportLocations

I am using VB.net, but any solution in C# will be very welcome.

The way I am doing it is:

1. I am adding a new Service Reference to http://www.flexiblecarhire.com/flexibleservice/fchxmlinterface.asmx and selecting fchXMLInterface > fchXMLInterfaceHttpPost
2. In my code I have: `Dim API As New ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoapClient`

When I run that, I am having an error message saying that:

> An endpoint configuration section for contract 'ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoap' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.

I checked the help at the first link I posted here and I could not find that. How can I fix that?

If I can't call this webservice as ServiceReference, how can I call this webservice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps i did try with the above web service and got back an invalid agentcode/password error message:

Click on Add web reference and add the URL and i have named it "CarHireRef" as the reference name and clicked OK.

Now my code to call a service looks as shown:

```
CarHireRef.fchXMLInterface ob = new CarHireRef.fchXMLInterface();
CarHireRef.ResultsGetLocations result = ob.GetAirportLocations("", "");
```

The above procedure does not have any config entry as i am adding a web reference and not a service reference.

Answer (score 3):

It has created configuration provided below when I added service reference. There you can see two endpoints for the same contact.
You should either specify endpoint name what you are going to use like

```
var a = new ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoapClient("fchXMLInterfaceSoap12");
```

or just remove unneeded endpoint configuration.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="fchXMLInterfaceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="fchXMLInterfaceSoap12">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
          messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
          realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://www.flexiblecarhire.com/flexibleservice/fchxmlinterface.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="fchXMLInterfaceSoap"
      contract="ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoap" name="fchXMLInterfaceSoap" />
  <endpoint address="http://www.flexiblecarhire.com/flexibleservice/fchxmlinterface.asmx"
      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="fchXMLInterfaceSoap12"
      contract="ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoap" name="fchXMLInterfaceSoap12" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever protocol is being called like basic, net.tcp or wshttp, that address should be in web config file remove other addresses from client section in app.config file, in my case i am calling the service as htp://machinename:700/test.svc but in the client section there were addresses with net.tcp and wshttp configurations, removed those addresses and issue is fixed for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
   [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
```

Add it in the interface file it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove customBinding from your web.config file inside `<system.serviceModel></system.serviceModel>`

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have two endpoints

```
<endpoint address="http://www.flexiblecarhire.com/flexibleservice/fchxmlinterface.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="fchXMLInterfaceSoap"
      contract="ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoap" name="fchXMLInterfaceSoap" />
  <endpoint address="http://www.flexiblecarhire.com/flexibleservice/fchxmlinterface.asmx"
      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="fchXMLInterfaceSoap12"
      contract="ServiceReference1.fchXMLInterfaceSoap" name="fchXMLInterfaceSoap12" />
</client
```

which are exactly the same, so the server doesn't know which endpoint you want to access. Just erase one and it'll be fine.